# Order of a principal ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose $I$ be an ideal of a ring $R$ such that $|I| = 33$. From this information, can we conclude that $I$ is principal?

I understand that with respect to addition, $I$ is a cyclic group here. This shows that $R$ is a commutative ring. From this stage I am not being able to move further.

Comment: I don't think that makes $R$ commutative.

Comment: Yes, you are right. $R$ may not be commutative.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot conclude that, at least without some mild assumptions.  Give the additive group $I = \mathbb{Z}_{33}$ the trivial multiplication $ab=0$ for all $a, b$.  Form any direct product of rings $I \times J$ and call this $R$.  Then $I$ (or really, $I \times \{0\}$) is an ideal of order $33$ in $R$, but it cannot be principal.  If $I \times \{0\}$ were principally generated by $(a,0)$, then products of the form $(x,y)(a,0)$ would eventually give all elements of $I \times \{0\}$ after multiplying by all elements $(x,y) \in R$.  But the first slot of such a product is always $xa=0$, so such products only generate the zero element (and are therefore missing 32 others).

Comment: So order of the ideal does not matter here. It may be anything positive, right?

Comment: Correct.  You can extrapolate this idea to work about anywhere.  (Note that in my example the rings do not have identity, which some people would disallow.)

Answer (score 1):

If your ring has identity, then yes.

The abelian group structure of $I$ would have to be $\mathbb Z_3\times\mathbb Z_{11} $, and therefore it is cyclic of order $33$.

So if $c$ is an element of additive order $33$, it is already enough that $\{n\cdot c\mid n\in \mathbb Z\}=I$.

This can break down when $I$ isn't a cyclic group. For example, in $F_2[x,y]/(x,y)^2$, where $(x,y)/(x,y)^2$ is not principal, the ideal has the underlying abelian group $F_2\times F_2$.

Comment: So we obtain $I = Rc = <c>$. But To get $Rc = <c>$, don't we need commutativity of $R$ here? Is the commutativity of $I$ enough here?

Comment: @SudiptaPurkait Sorry, somewhere I decided you were assuming commutativity. But it does not matter. You already have $c\mathbb Z=I$, and you've already assumed $I$ is an ideal, everything is fine.

Comment: It is fine now. I was facing some notational problem.